# Flutter: Execution failed for task ':flutter_webrtc:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webrtc, connectycube

I tried to creating a build for my flutter app  but it throws me an error. Can someone help?

Execution failed for task ':flutter_webrtc:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':flutter_webrtc:compileReleaseKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':flutter_webrtc:releaseCompileClasspath'.
> > Failed to transform android-104.5112.05.jar (com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.05) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Could not find android-104.5112.05.jar (com.github.webrtc-sdk:android:104.5112.05).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://jitpack.io/com/github/webrtc-sdk/android/104.5112.05/android-104.5112.05.jar

In project level build.gradle in add this
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10' & classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'

And in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, i add this.
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

Java Version: 17.0.6
connectycube_sdk: 2.3.0
Flutter Version: 3.7.6

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Connectycube Flutter SDK in your project try to update it to the newest version ([2.4.1](https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_sdk/versions/2.4.1)) it should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in  build.gradle. follow below structure.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

then invalidate cache. i hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, I also tried this, but did not get any success.

Comment: are you using this flutter package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc?

Comment: I am using  connectycube_sdk https://pub.dev/packages/connectycube_sdk/versions/2.3.0 which is dependent on webrtc.

Comment: @wasiqhussain try version 2.4.1, the issue should be fixed there